# why are the calculator's buttons not responsive when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a calculator project using JavaScript but the buttons are not responsive. Below is the JavaScript snippet for the equals button. What is the problem?

```
    equalsButton.addEventListener('click',button => {                              
        calculator.compute()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
```

Comment: How did you get the equalsButton ?

Comment: You need to add your HTML and preferably create a Stackoverflow snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: @sabbir.alam, it is a variable which stores the equals sign.